# Undefined reference, presume makefile is not using headerfiles

Tags: c++, makefile, undefined-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main (void)
{
    // Nothing here. 
}
```

I am using Makefile to compile.

```
CXXFLAGS    = -std=c++11 -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJS        = ProgramEntry.o

LIBS        =

TARGET      = Reading

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Resulting in undefined reference.

```
undefined reference to --
```

I think makefile is not using any header file. May I know how to fix the make file, in case if I add a directory for header files.

Comment: Looks more like a linker error to me.

Comment: @user1320881 These are linker errors, but they can be caused by makefile errors (e.g., an object file is not rebuild because it does not depend on a header which changed)

Answer (score 3):

It is using the headers, or you'd get a compiler error, not a linkage error.

Change the following line to this:

```
OBJS        = ProgramEntry.o GetNodes.o GetElements.o MeshData.o
```

Or

```
OBJS        = *.o
```

To add all objects in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to add all *.o files. Since I may add or remove *.cpp files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're only linking in one of your object files, so the functions defined in the others don't make it into your program.

Add all your `.o`s to `OBJS`. That appears to be the point of that variable, after all?